# Bottle a beer that was stuck at fermentation?

Tags: fermentation, bottling, stuck-fermentation, imperial

6 Months ago I attempted a KBS Clone.
Beer uses chocolate, coffee, bourbon soaked oak.

I got 1.090 OG and got stuck at 1.032, but it tastes really good (Can chocolate make it appear higher?)
It's been 6 months and I would like to bottle it. What technique should I use if I want to bottle condition?

I'm scared that if I repitch an high attenuative yeast, I might restart fermentation and make bottles bombs.. Is that a possibility?

Thanks

Comment: Did you have any lactose in the recipe?  That’s not fermentable and would explain high FG.

Comment: No lactose, but chocolate

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the estimated FG of the recipe?

There are two possibilities:

1- Your fermentation is done (not stuck), but you can confirm this by trying to restart it.  High FG is usually caused by uncontrolled mash temperature (too high or too low) which results in too much non fermentable sugars (unconverted).  No problem to bottle at this point.

2- Your fermentation is stuck for some reason (mostly inadequate temperature, old yeast, etc.).  Bring it back to correct temperature, add some more yeast and mix lightly.  If fermentation does not restart, it is possible that you reached the FG.

If you think that there are no reasons for a stuck fermentation, go ahead and bottle condition your beer.  Otherwise I would make sure fermentation is done.

Comment: I used us05 which supports 11abv I think. Am I safe to use the same kind of yeast? My mash temperature was precise, but I didn't have the knowledge about water chemistry at this time and I suspect my PH was off.. So I think I'm gonna test a small amount of yeast in my 1 gallon and observe.

Comment: True, water pH will affect mash efficiency as well.